# How to identify the request coming from same system or not of the ASP.NET Web API

Tags: angular, session, asp.net-web-api, token, penetration-testing

We have created ASP.NET Web API which we are calling from an Angular application and some client applications.

Generating a token upon customer login and passing in subsequent API calls, storing in localstorage through Angular application.

But the customer token generated in one session / browser, if we copy and use it in another session / browser - it is working.

Ideal scenario - it should not work. Please suggest us a solution.

We have tried to get session id from request.context but it is giving different for each call of the API, so it was not helpful.

Comment: What are you using for your identity provider?

Comment: yes it should work since the server it will be checking for that session, so if you don't want it to work consider using session which will valid for specific period of time